# Prolog Or(;) Rule Return Multiple Result

Tags: prolog, rule

i have define a rule with or operator but it return multiple true or false.

```
isloanaccept(Name,Guarantor,LoanType,LoanAmount,LoanTenure) 
:-  customer(Name,bank(_),customertype(_),
 citizen(Ci),age(Age),credit(C),
 income(I),property(_),bankemployee(_)), 
 Ci == 'malaysian',
 Age >= 18,
 C > 500, 
    I > (LoanAmount / LoanTenure) / 12,
 isguarantor(Guarantor,Name), 
 ispersonalloan(LoanType,LoanAmount,LoanTenure);
 ishouseloan(LoanType,LoanAmount,LoanTenure);
 isbusinessloan(LoanType,LoanAmount,LoanTenure);
 iscarloan(LoanType,LoanAmount,LoanTenure).
```

Actually, i need to check whether the loan type is fulfill the particular loan requirement and combine with general rule.

In other words, i need to define the rule above like this.

```
Ci == 'malaysian', Age >= 18,C > 500, 
I > (LoanAmount / LoanTenure) / 12,
isguarantor(Guarantor,Name) 
    Or with   (ispersonalloan(LoanType,LoanAmount,LoanTenure);
             ishouseloan(LoanType,LoanAmount,LoanTenure);
             isbusinessloan(LoanType,LoanAmount,LoanTenure);
             iscarloan(LoanType,LoanAmount,LoanTenur)
```

It should return 1 true/false rather than multiple statement in the command line.

Each of the or rule return 1 boolean value which is not i want after  have checked the rule in command line. I need to have like this (General Rule & (Multiple Or Rule) ).

How to combine several or rule which return 1 boolean value ?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just surround all your "or'ed" goals with `once`.

e.g.

```
once(
 ispersonalloan(LoanType,LoanAmount,LoanTenure);
 ishouseloan(LoanType,LoanAmount,LoanTenure);
 isbusinessloan(LoanType,LoanAmount,LoanTenure);
 iscarloan(LoanType,LoanAmount,LoanTenure)
).
```

Now, the "or'ed" goals either succeed or fail.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should put `(` and `)` around your target combined with `;`. Because currently it interprets it like disjunction of `customer(...),...,isguarantor(Guarantor,Name), ispersonalloan(...)`, `ishouseloan(...)`, ..., `iscarloan(...)`. That's because different priorities of operators `,` and `;`.

Actually `;` - means real "or", not "mutual exclusive or" and not "in other case". So if "ishouseloan" can' succeed together with "ispersonalloan" than you'll have several successful targets. In this example `once/1` may help (as well `not(not(...))`), but you can try to get prolog deeper with your task and specify non-everlapping targets like (I do some personal assumptions about overlapping `isXXX`):

```
isloan(LT, Am, T):-
  (ishouseloan(LT,Am,T)
  ;iscarloan(LT,AM,T)
  ;not((ishouseloan(LT,Am,T);iscarloan(LT,AM,T))),
    (ispersonalloan(LT,Am,T)
    ;isbusinessloan(LT,Am,T)
    )
  )
```

In this case you should be able to generate all loans when your `LT`, `Am` and `T` is not yet bound to specific values and those `isXXX` can bind free variables.